# Fill column hierarchically or recursively

Tags: python, pandas, na

I want to create a new column [`new_var`] based on variable_1. If variable_1 is NA, then use variable_2. If both of them are NA, then leave them as NA.

Is there an smarter way to do it than below? The solution wouldn't scale up well if I had 4 or 5 variables.

```
df['new_var'] = df['variable_1']

df.loc[(df['new_var'].isna()) & (df['variable_2'].notna()), 'new_var'] = df.loc[(df['new_var'].isna()) & (df['variable_2'].notna()), 'variable_2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bfill`:

> The solution wouldn't scale up well if I had 4 or 5 variables.

```
cols = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
df['new_var'] = df[cols].bfill(axis=1)[cols[0]]
print(df)

# Output:
   var1  var2  var3  new_var
0   3.0   4.0   9.0      3.0
1   NaN   8.0   5.0      8.0
2   NaN   NaN   6.0      6.0
3   NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [3, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   'var2': [4, 8, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   'var3': [9, 5, 6, np.NaN]})
```

---

**Old answers: only work for 2 variables**

Use `fillna`:

```
df['new_var'] = df['var1'].fillna(df['var2'])
print(df)

# Output:
   var1  var2  new_var
0   3.0   4.0      3.0
1   NaN   8.0      8.0
2   NaN   NaN      NaN
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [3, np.NaN, np.NaN], 'var2': [4, 8, np.NaN]})
```

**Update**

You can also use `combine_first`:

```
df['new_var'] = df['var1'].combine_first(df['var2'])
print(df)

# Output:
   var1  var2  new_var
0   3.0   4.0      3.0
1   NaN   8.0      8.0
2   NaN   NaN      NaN
```

Comment: thanks, this is the level of smartness I am missing!

Comment: In fact `fillna` can work with `df[cols].fillna(method='bfill', axis=1)[cols[0]]` but `bfill` is more straightforward. (Thanks for your vote)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer without example data, but I guess you should simply `pandas.where`:

```
df['new_var'] = df['variable_2'].where(df['variable_1'].isna())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['new_var'] = np.where(df['variable_1'].isna(), df['variable_2'], df['variable_1'])
```